# Serving API routes and web routes on different ports

Tags: laravel

I have some api routes that are related to my REST API and some web routes that are related to my admin panel. my employee asked me to serve API routes on a specific port and the admin panel on another port so we can block all requests to admin panel from everywhere except the local network. My question is that how can I serve the routes that are in api.php file on a specific port and serve all routes from the web.php file on another port.

Is there another way to prevent everyone from the internet to access the web.php routes???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A different approach than registering or not the routes proposed by @rostik-hvostik is to verify through middlewares.

it offers more flexibility on where we can use it.

**app/Http/Middleware/ListenPort.php**

```php
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class ListenPort
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next, ...$ports)
    {
        // I'm not sure if $ports is an array of string or integer though
        if (in_array($request->getPort(), $ports, true)) {
            return $next($request);
        }

        abort(403);

    }
}
```

**app/Http/Kernel.php**

```php
protected $routeMiddleware = [
        'listen' => \App\Http\Middleware\ListenPort::class,
]

protected $middlewareGroups = [
        'web' => [
            ...,
            'listen:80',
        ],

        'api' => [
            ...,
            'listen:8000',
        ],
];
```

Answer (score 2):

Open `RouteServiceProvider` and add some conditions

```
public function map()
{
    if (request()->getPort() === 8000) {
        $this->mapApiRoutes();
    }

    if (request()->getPort() === 80) {
        $this->mapWebRoutes();
    }
}
```

But do not forget to add in the configuration of your web server port listen

[Nginx](https://serverfault.com/questions/655067/is-it-possible-to-make-nginx-listen-to-different-ports):

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen 8000;
    server_name example.org;
    root /var/www/;
}
```

[Apache](https://serverfault.com/questions/28041/how-do-i-make-apache-web-server-listen-on-two-different-ports):

```
Listen 80
Listen 8000
```

Comment: Does this works when you cache the routes? I would use a middleware instead

Comment: No, becouse when you call `php artisan route:cache` locally it call from **80** port, good idea to add custom .env like .env.artisan add some parameter APP_ENV=artisan, and add this in each `if (request()->getPort() === 8000 || app()->environment() === 'artisan') {` and call `php artisan route:cache --env=artisan`